# ToString() is returning System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem: before the value

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, tostring, listboxitem

I am trying to pass all the items in a listbox to a list.

```
foreach (ListItem li in MyListBox.Items)
{
    MyList.Add(li.ToString());
}
```

The result looks like:

> System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem: item 1
>
> System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem: item 2

Is there a way to stop System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem: showing before the value of each item, or a better way to send my listboxitems into my string list?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`Value`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem.value%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) property of the control :

```
MyList.Add(li.Value);
```

or [`Text`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem.text(v=vs.110).aspx) property of it :

```
MyList.Add(li.Text);
```

which depends what you actually need to be added in the collection.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately neither Text nor Value is a property of a `ListBoxItem`.

In my XAML I tried 2 ways to specify the text:
(Sorry, this forum does not allow anything with angle brackets to be posted.)
Both show the text just fine.

However, when I try to get the text of the selected item it always has
`System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem`: in the string.

```
var commandItem = Commands.SelectedItem;
var command = commandItem.ToString();
```

Comment: I figured it out.  When using the XAML for a ListBox, it contains ListBoxItems.  When populating a ListBox in code I was using strings.  To get just the intended string, without the preceding junk, I did this: var x = ((ListBoxItem)Commands.SelectedItem).Content.ToString();